# Not able to open a pdf file using https - Internet Explorer cannot download filename

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have this snippet of VB Script code on one of our asp page.

```
Response.Clear
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader "Cache-Control", "public"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "public"   
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf"
Response.BinaryWrite objPDF
Response.Flush
```

Our client links to this page like this,
    a href="https://www.oursite.com/pdf.asp?fileid=12345"

The pdf link works fine in FF, but not in IE. IE throws this - Internet Explorer cannot download pdf.asp error. It works if it's http instead of https.

Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

Set content to not to expire immediately using IIS. In IIS 5.0, 5.1, and 6.0, the option to set content expiration can be found on the HTTP Headers tab in the Internet Services Manager. In IIS 7.0 and later, the option to set content expiration can be found within the HTTP Response Headers feature.

Let this be the starting point for your seeked solution;
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=317208